# Sum tables MySQL

Tags: mysql, sum

I have 4 tables in my database. 2012,2013,2014,2015.

Each one is laid out as so:

[image]

I would like to sum each StartStation for each year as so:

```
StartStation         2012  2013   2014  2015
10th & E St NW        X     Y      Z     ...
10th & Monroe St NE   X     Y      Z     ...
......
```

Thank you!!

Comment: Change it into one table and add a year column

Comment: And the pivot the results. Or just union the tables and then pivot them.

Comment: 'Change it into one table and add a year column' ... and handle the remaining display issue in application level code

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I am new to MySQL. I am doing this for a school report - I don't care about the database structure. I just need the data in that table so I can compare the data from each year and analyse it. What method do you suggest? Thank you very much

Comment: @Jack does every table have an entry for every station?

Comment: I believe so yes.

Comment: I would like to see data for each station for each year side-by-side. E.g. Station X: 2012value,  2013value, 2014value, 2015value. From that I can then make comparisons for each year easily

Comment: And what's a StationTerminal?

Comment: Sorry I meant StartStation - StationTerminal is a mistake. I meant startstation

Comment: Can you help me @Strawberry

Comment: I can only really refer you to my original comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
  t1.startstation,
  t1.totalcount `2012`,
  t2.totalcount `2013`,
  t3.totalcount `2014`,
  t4.totalcount `2015`
from test.`2012` t1
join test.`2013` t2 on t2.startstation = t1.startstation
join test.`2014` t3 on t3.startstation = t1.startstation
join test.`2015` t4 on t4.startstation = t1.startstation
```

Comment: Hi, I am getting error code 1064: there is an error in your sql syntax. I assume I need to change some of that to my own database. my database is called 'test' so I assume I need to change mytable_2012 to test.2012 ??

Comment: Also, what is t1, t2 etc?

Comment: Try query now. `use test` first to switch to database called "test".. `t1` etc are *aliases*, which I used so I could refer to the strangely named tables without going blind on back ticks.

Comment: Hi, I am getting an error saying: "no database selected". Sorry I am such a noob. I changed all the 2012, 2013 etc to 'test.2012' etc. but still get nothing

Comment: @Jack you can't use `'test.2012'` (quotes mean backticks) - that makes the table name *literally* `"test.2012"`. You need `'test'.'2012'` (again quotes should be backticks). Or execute `use test` to start using the `test` database (assuming you are using mysql CLI).

Comment: Hi please look could you look at the screenshot. https://www.dropbox.com/s/zqlcq4ni05zwoqc/Screen%20Shot%202016-10-31%20at%2011.24.31.png?dl=0

Comment: @JackMorgan you have *quotes* around the dots  - replace them all with back ticks. Unfortunately I can't show backticks in a comment, but I've edited the answer. Note that you don't need backticks around "test", because "test" doesn't have any special meaning

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT StartStation AS "Station Name", SUM(`2012`) AS `2012`, SUM(`2013`) AS `2013`, SUM(`2014`) AS `2014`, SUM(`2015`) AS `2015` FROM (
    (SELECT StartStation, TotalCount AS `2012`, 0 AS `2013`, 0 AS `2014`, 0 AS `2015` FROM `2012`) 
    UNION ALL 
    (SELECT StartStation, 0 AS `2012`, TotalCount AS `2013`, 0 AS `2014`, 0 AS `2014` FROM `2013`) 
    UNION ALL 
    (SELECT StartStation, 0 AS `2012`, 0 AS `2013`, TotalCount AS `2014`, 0 AS `2015` FROM `2014`) 
    UNION ALL 
    (SELECT StartStation, 0 AS `2012`, 0 AS `2013`, 0 AS `2014`, TotalCount AS `2014` FROM `2015`)   
) AS u 
GROUP BY StartStation
```

Comment: Or of course you can merge data into one table of create view (better). Answer above assume that you can't/don't want to change database struct

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I am new to MySQL. I am doing this for a school report - I don't care about the database structure. I just need the data in that table so I can compare the data from each year and analyse it. What method do you suggest? Thank you very much

Comment: You should do 4 queries (one query to every table). Template of query you have above - simply change table name and you got your results.

Comment: I need the station name side by side for each year side by side: e.g:                               Station1:    2012Value    2013 Value    2014Value    2015Value            Station2:    2012Value    2013 Value    2014Value    2015Value

Comment: I need to query all 4 at the same time so I can compare each one side by side. So I can look at stationX and see the different value for each year. Thank you

Comment: U forgot mentioned in what programming language you do that. You simply need to do (in that programming language) a loops with these queries, merge results into - for example - arrays then display it in preffered way :)

Comment: Dont forget to give +1 :)

Comment: MySQL. Please could you help!! This is so urgent and I can't do it :(

Comment: In my opinion this problem is resolved. Coding problem is done. Now you should use tips above to make your problem done :) remember you can use phpMyAdmin for example and export SQL query results to xls files - if you are not developer this shape will be better for you

Comment: All I need is a table like `Station Name  2012  2013  2014  2015`  so I can see them side by side. I already have 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015 in separate spreadsheets in excel. I just want one table with all the years side by side